# Travis CI not finding my app

Tags: heroku, travis-ci

I have been trying to figure out this error message I keep getting in TravisCI.
[image]

The build is set up to deploy to heroku, but it doesn't work.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Please include message text [in your question](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/), not images and not as links to external sites.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow - since links can die, it's better if you embed the image, or better yet, since the image is of text - simply copy and paste the actual text.